# Как добавить телеграмм бота (самопис) в канал, если там больше 200 подписчиков?(Уже решил проблему)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот

Когда пытался добавить по обычному выдало, что в канале более 200 подписчиков и вот ссылка на приглашение, а как мне заставить бота перейти по этой ссылке я хз..

Что мне нужно по итогу: Чтобы бот смог перейти по ссылке и подписаться на канал, либо же узнать другие способы как его добавить.

Вот код какой щас есть:

```
import telebot
import config

bot_token = config.token

chat_id = (тут айди чата моего второго пустого канала(чтобы через него добавить бота в основной))


channel_id = ...
channel_username = ... #Username канала

bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Канал ваш? Бот не переходит по ссылкам и не подписывается, вы как администратор канала должны самостоятельно добавить бота.

Comment: Канал мой, но добавить участника в канал не могу, пишет, что более 200 участников в канале и вот только по ссылке можно добавлять теперь

Comment: Если вы решили проблему, то пожалуйста, либо отметьте ответ, который вам помог как "решение" (галка рядом с ответом), либо ответьте на свой собственный вопрос, описав, как вы решили проблему (это поможет другим посетителям с такой же проблемой)

Comment: Подождите, если вы решили проблему самостоятельно, лучше ответить на свой же вопрос и поставить галочку как решение. Если же вы мне поставили галочку из-за недопонимания, а мой ответ не является решением, то он может запутать других участников в дальнейшем.

Comment: Ваш комментарий правильный, единственное, что это должен всё делать именно создатель канала, админы канала даже с фулл правами не смогут пригласить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Как добавить в канал](https://developers.sber.ru/help/salutebot/adding-to-telegram#kak-dobavit-v-kanal)

В канале чат-боты используются для отложенных публикаций или как путеводитель по каналу. Чтобы робот мог создавать посты или иначе действовать от имени канала, нужно сделать его администратором. Вот как это сделать:

- Зайдите в телеграм-канал, нажмите на три точки и выберите «Управление каналом».
- Перейдите в раздел «Администраторы».
- В поиске найдите бот по системному имени через @имя.
- Добавьте его в качестве администратора и укажите, какие разрешения у него должны быть. Если не выдать нужное разрешение, то некоторые функции могут не работать.

В канал можно добавить собственный бот или выбрать уже существующий.

Comment: Если в канале более 200 человек так просто его добавить нельзя

Comment: Помогло, самое главное, чтобы добавлял СОЗДАТЕЛЬ канала, а не админы